# How to remove a certain string before printing?

Tags: python

```
answer = input('Enter a number: ')
x = 10**(len(answer) - 1)
print(answer, end = ' = ')
for i in answer: 
    if '0' in i:
        x = x//10
        continue
    else:
        print('(' + i + ' * ' + str(x) + ')' , end = '')
        x = x//10
        print(' + ', end = '')
```

so i have this problem, when i enter any number, everything is great but at the end there is an extra ' + ' that i do not want. Now normally this wouldnt be an issue with lists and .remove function, however i am not allowed to use these for this problem. I cannot come up with any sort of solution that does not involve functions

I tried matching the length but it didnt work because of '0'

Comment: One easy way to fix this is to put all of your terms into a `list` and then do `print(' + '.join(terms))`

Comment: A bit besides the point, but `if i == '0'` is much clearer in above context than `if '0' in i`.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert an extra condition in the else block:

```
else:
    print('(' + i + ' * ' + str(x) + ')' , end = '')
    x = x//10
    if x:
        print(' + ', end = '')
```

this will help not to insert the last plus when it is not needed

Comment: this does not work if inserted number is a multiple of 10 :(

Comment: you are right. in that way i think the best solution have @hai-vu in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74451500/20513338) down. just use the list and f-strings.

Comment: i cannot use f strings and lists. this is an easy challenge, what makes it hard is that i am not allowed to use ANY functions other than print input and len :( any solutions i can think of are ugly and 30+ lines long

Answer (score 0):

The error is that there is an extra '+' at the end of the output. This can be fixed by adding an 'if' statement to the end of the code that checks if the last character in the output is a '+' and, if so, removes it.

Answer (score 0):

Well Valery's answer is the best just add one more condition in case the answer was a 10 multiple

```
if x and int(answer)%10 != 0:
```

Comment: maybe ive added this wrong but when this is implemented and the answer is a multiple of 10, all + get removed from all of the code

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is best solved using the `str.join()` method.

```py
answer = input("Enter a number: ")
x = 10**(len(answer) - 1)

terms = []
for i in answer: 
    if i == "0":
        x = x//10
        continue
    else:
        terms.append(f"({i} * {x})")
        x = x//10

print(f"{answer} =", " + ".join(terms))
```

Sample interaction:

```
Enter a number: 1025
1025 = (1 * 1000) + (2 * 10) + (5 * 1)
```

**Notes**

- We build up the terms by appending them into the list `terms`
- At the end of the for loop, given 1025 as the input, the `terms` looks like this

  ['(1 * 1000)', '(2 * 10)', '(5 * 1)']

## Update

Here is a patch of your original solution:

```py
answer = input('Enter a number: ')
x = 10**(len(answer) - 1)
print(answer, end = ' = ')
for i in answer: 
    if '0' in i:
        x = x//10
        continue
    else:
        print('(' + i + ' * ' + str(x) + ')' , end = '')
        x = x//10
        if x == 0:
            print()
        else:
            print(' + ', end = '')
```

The difference is in the last 4 lines where `x` (poor name, by the way), reaches 0, we know that we should not add any more plus signs.

Comment: as i said, this would be easy to do with lists, and im already good enough in python to implement them, however for this specific challenge no functions are allowed other than print input and len

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = input('Enter a number: ')

#finds length of answer
length = 0
for n in answer:
    length += 1
loop_counter = 0
##


zero_counter = 0
multiple_of_ten = 10

#finds if answer is multiple of 10 and if so by what magnitude
while True:   
    if int(answer) % multiple_of_ten == 0:
        #counts the zeroes aka multiple of 10
        zero_counter += 1
        multiple_of_ten = multiple_of_ten*10
    else:
        break

#finds the multiple of 10 needed for print output
x = 10**(length - 1)

print(answer, end = ' = ')
for i in answer:
    # if its a 0 it will skip
    if '0' in i:
        x = x//10
        #still divises x by 10 for the next loop
        pass
    else:
        print('(' + i + ' * ' + str(x) + ')' , end = '')
        x = x//10
        
        #if position in loop and zeroes remaining plus one is equal to
        #the length of the integer provided, it means all the reamining
        #digits are 0
        if loop_counter + zero_counter + 1 == length:
            break
        else:
        #adds ' + ' between strings
            print(' + ', end = '')

    # keeps track of position in loop
    loop_counter += 1
```

ended up implementing a counter to see how many zeroes there are, and a counter to see where we are in the for loop and stop the loop when its the same as amount of zeroes remaining

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it worked fine

```
if x and int(answer)%10 != 0:

Enter a number: 25
25 = (2 * 10) + (5 * 1)

Enter a number: 1000
1000 = (1 * 1000)

Enter a number: 117
117 = (1 * 100) + (1 * 10) + (7 * 1)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?